# How to add markers on to a googlemaps javascript api from a MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, google-maps

I have made a database in MySQL with some information and long/lat data in it. I would like this data to appear on my google maps page as markers, so that I do not have to manually add markers to a script.

I have followed several tutorials and have tried several scripts, with the one shown below being the only one that didn't come up with errors for me. However,  the markers do not appear on the map. I have mainly followed instructions from this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

My data does appear on the xml file as it states in the tutorial, having a look at my sourcecode for the map I find the following error at line 54 of the index.html script:
Uncaught ReferenceError: customLabel is not defined

I have tried fixing this, but I end up messing up the entire script. My question is, could anyone help me fix this error so that my markers appear on the map created in the index.html file?

I have 3 separate scripts: a *"config.php"* for my log in details, a *"maps_xml.php"* to call the data and an *"index.html"* to make the map and add the data as markers.

**Config script:**

```
<?php
$username="mydatabase_username";
$password="12345";
$database="mydatabase";
?>
```

**Maps_XML.php script:**

```
<?php
require("config.php");
function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}
// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM userlocations WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
echo '<markers>';
$ind=0;
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'id="' . $row['id'] . '" ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
  $ind = $ind + 1;
}
// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
?>
```

*
**Index.html script:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>User locations</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

<html>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.153844, 5.942341),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('maps_xml.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_APIKEY &callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the output of `maps_xml.php`?  Is it valid XML?  Have you followed the steps in [this tutorial, under "checking that xml output works"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps#checking-that-xml-output-works)?

Comment: I have indeed, when I connect to it, it comes up with an error on line 1 and states that the document is empty, but going into the sources with F12 it shows that it connected successfully and it also shows the data inside the database. Removing the "header("Content-type: text/xml");" line in the script and then loading the page, also states that the connection was successful.

Comment: And that line in the output means that the output is not a valid xml file...

Comment: Which means that`maps_xml.php` (which you haven't provided the code for, unless it is what you call "MapsXML script") is what needs to be fixed. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: If the code listed as **MapsXML script** is `maps_xml.php`, one issue is this line: `echo "Connected successfully";`, it is not valid XML.

Comment: It is indeed the code listed as MapsXML, I apologize for the confusion. I have been trying to figure out where the xml turns invalid and how to fix it, removing the "Connected successfully" didn't do the job. A lot of the errors point back to  `echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";`, saying that it does not belong in the prolong. I am trying to figure out how to fix this. Thank you for all your help and information so far.